# Python Selenium ChromeDriver: chromedriver dummy frame

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I had this simple login script to facebook that used to work perfectly until about a month ago. But yesterday when I tried running it again I got this dummy page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head></head>
  <body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
    </pre>
    <iframe name="chromedriver dummy frame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I guess they've added some new detections. Is there a way to avoid those?
This is my simplified code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'])
browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
for line in browser.page_source.split('\n'):
    print line
```

Comment: what version of Selenium you are using as using you simplified code on my machine with selenium 3.3.1 I am not getting any dummy form. try to update your selenium, hope it might help

Comment: I am also getting the normal facebook login page. Web scraping is against their ToS (I believe), so it's possibly that either your IP address or machine's fingerprint have been blacklisted. You could try running your script from a different network and/or through a proxy to see. You could also try manually setting a different user agent to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem which is not Facebook but our developing pages.

> I might be ssl problem. (which might be solved `--ignore-ssl-... option`.)
>   Mostly, This is `waiting` problem.
>   The Selenium bot captures whole `HTML PAGE` before the server print out their contexts.
>   Thus, it might be solved, using same `wait options` ([See this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html))

If there is some `unique` ID html elements, please insert following codes:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'unique')))
```